# How to communicate between Raspberry Pis using WiFi?

Tags: communication

How do I communicate between 2 Raspberry Pis with WiFi dongles? I have connected the 2 WiFi dongles to the router but I do not know the next step of how to get them to communicate. For in this case I'm using the network for 2 micro mouse to communicate.

Comment: It somewhat depends on what you're asking -- is it a programming question?  Or it networking?  Do you write a program which will exchange information between the two Pis?  Or do you want to use existing software (e.g. curl) on PiA to retrieve data from a server (e.g. Apache httpd) on PiB?

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple approaches to accomplish what you want.  They way I am going to describe is probably going to have a learning curve though, because I used [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29).  Most of the information I used came from [this **very** helpful guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html).

With this method, you are going to need a [client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_%28computing%29) and a [server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29) to communicate between the two Raspberry Pis.  The exchange of information between client and server is summarized in this diagram:

[image]

---

Here is some C code for a server and client.  All this server does is send the string "Hello, World!\n" out over a stream connection. All you need to do to test this server is run it in one window, and telnet to it from another with:

```
$ telnet remotehostname 3490
```

(where remotehostname is the name of the machine you're running it on)

Here is the `server.c` code:

```
/*
** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the `client.c` code:

```
/*
** client.c -- a stream socket client demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "3490" // the port client will be connecting to 

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

You can read further into that guide I linked to learn how to develop more advanced communication between clients and servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use almost any of your favourite programming languages for this...

- [Perl](http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-write-simple-tcp-server-and-client-in-perl.html)
- [Java](http://royalexander.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/sending-objects-via-high-speed-asynchronous-sockets-in-c-serialization-socket-programming/)
- [MONO.NET](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Each of those have some kind of communication library to create Net Sockets, like virtual UART ports where you can send binary or text data at a high level while the libraries handle error and flow control transparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run WiFi over Pis without having to connect it your Router (Infrastructure) you might want them to run on ad-hoc network i.e. You would not need a Router and don't have to connect it to the internet.

#### Warning

When you want to achieve the above mentioned ad-hoc mode you might want to buy the right kind of **WiFi Adapters** which specifically run the *ad-hoc mode* then you will have to buy **RALINK Chipset** based WiFi adapters. Mostly the community uses the **EDIMAX 7811UN** WiFi Adapter - which is great if you want to connect to the Internet *Infrastructure* mode but if you want to the Pis to *talk - to- each other* then make sure you buy the right kind of WiFi Adapters.

If you want, you can have  a look at [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157743/raspberry-pi-and-edimax-7811un-incompatibility-in-ad-hoc-mode/34458131#34458131) if you want a better understanding of the issue I am trying to address.