# How do I send data from the Raspberry Pi to the PC

Tags: gpio, wireless, wifi, communication

My project is to use the Raspberry Pi to send data taken from the  "micromouse" to the PC.

The micromouse will run in the maze, and then data will be sent to the Raspberry Pi most likely through the serial port to pin 8 & 10 of the GPIO pins. Then that data will be sent to a PC via wirelessly.

How do I send the data via wireless from the Raspberry Pi to the PC, and how do I know that the data is stored in the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to communicate between Raspberry Pis using WiFi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/how-to-communicate-between-raspberry-pis-using-wifi)

Comment: This question has already been asked before, as well as a duplicate of this question.  Please do some research before asking a question here.  That is the point of school work (which is what this looks like it is).

Comment: I'm working on Raspberry to make Energy meter and I also want send all measuring parameter to web.
may you help me please?

Answer (score 5):

If both Raspberry Pi and the PC are inside the same Network then you can send data to the PC using a web server,

Start by setting up a simple server based on [web.py](http://webpy.org/), which is installed via 
apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-webpy
```

Now create a directory to put the code in and create a simple test program

```
mkdir webpy
cd webpy
nano server.py
```

Now let's write a test code.
write this inside `server.py` (make sure you are in a root mode)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Save it and then set it as executable with

```
chmod +x server.py
```

and then run the code

```
./server.py
```

you will see something like this showing the server is waiting for a request (pressing Ctrl+C will stop the server)

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

Now from your PC, point your browser at `http://ip-address-of-your-pi:8080` and it will show a web page with the content of `Hello, world!`.

If everything works as intended, you are all good to Go.
Replace the content of `server.py` with the data you need to communicate from Raspberry Pi to the PC.

From your pc, you can read the data using `urllib` library of Python (the code below is for python 2.x)

```
import urllib
link = "http://192.168.1.65:8080" # Change this address to your settings
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
date = myfile.split(" ")
```

You now have the data from your Raspberry Pi into your PC.

Comment: I just have to install using sudo apt-get install python-webpy then I just start by keying in mkdir webpy and so on right? ,what do you mean by root mode ? sudo su?Thn My problem is (after keying in ./server.py):Traceback (most recent calls last):File "./server.py",line 15,in <module> app=web.apllication(urls,globals()) attributeerror:'module' object has no attribute 'application'.

Comment: The step `./server.py` returns:

`~/web.py-0.33/webpy $ ./server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import web
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/web/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/db/__init__.py", line 69
    print "var", var
              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("var", var)?`

But I find no "print". What could be the reason?

Comment: ...turns out the problem was solved by `pip install web.py==0.40.dev0`

Comment: Is your code python-3-compatible? What do I need to change? I get the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 13, in <module>
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.init_mapping(mapping)
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 130, in init_mapping
    self.mapping = list(utils.group(mapping, 2))
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/web/utils.py", line 531, in group
    x = list(take(seq, size))
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration`

Answer (score 0):

EWD.js could be a possible solution:

ewdGateway2 includes an entirely WebSocket-based framework known as EWD.js.

[image]

https://github.com/robtweed/ewdGateway2

Full Documentation

http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/download/EWDjsMechanics.pdf